# Using Printed Output for Dataframe Generation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make data frames based off the string name of a unit. Consider:

```
import pandas as pd

# Imports our data

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/synth-inference/synthdid/master/data/california_prop99.csv', 
sep=';', parse_dates=['Year'], index_col='Year')


# Sorts our data
df = df.sort_values(by=['State', 'Year'])


# Generates a unique ID for our units-- why doesn't it begin from 1?
df['id'] = df.State.map(hash)



# Stores the treated units names in a list
treatedunit = df[df['treated']==1].State.unique().tolist()


# Checks we only have ONE treated unit

assert len(treatedunit) == 1


# Extracts the unique ID of the treated unit


df[df['treated']==1]['id'].describe().loc['min']


# Extract its name from the list

res = [treatedunit[0]]


# Putting it in 'quotes'


trname = print(str(res)[1:-1])


# Now we create a dataframe based on its name

df_treat = df[df['State'] == trname]

df_treat
```

What I hoped for, was for Python to generate a new dataframe with only the values for California in it. Instead, I get an empty dataframe. When I do this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/synth-inference/synthdid/master/data/california_prop99.csv', 
sep=';', parse_dates=['Year'], index_col='Year')


df = df.sort_values(by=['State', 'Year'])

df['id'] = df.State.map(hash)

df[df['treated']==1]['id'].describe().loc['min']

treatedunit = df[df['treated']==1].State.unique().tolist()

res = [treatedunit[0]]

df_treat = df[df['State'] == 'California']

df_treat
```

Python gives me what I expect. But I must generalize this, since the treated unit of interest won't always be California. So, how might I get Python to know `trname` is meant to be `'California'` instead of an empty dataframe?

Comment: I haven't read in much detail, but I can tell you that the `print` function returns `None`, so `trname = print ...` will cause `trname` to be `None`

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it is possible to do

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/synth-inference/synthdid/master/data/california_prop99.csv', 
sep=';', parse_dates=['Year'], index_col='Year')


df = df.sort_values(by=['State', 'Year'])

df['id'] = df.State.map(hash)

trid = df[df['treated']==1]['id'].describe().loc['min']

df_treat = df[df['id'] == trid]
df_treat
```

But, I do *still* want to know how to do it using the string, too.